# How to import Socket.IO using ES6 import syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, socket.io

[Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#) says:

> Exposed as the `io` namespace in the standalone build, or the result
>   of calling `require('socket.io-client')`.
>
> ```
> const io = require('socket.io-client');
> // or with import syntax
> import io from 'socket.io-client';
> ```

But if I try that:

```
import io from "/socket.io/socket.io.js";
```

There's an error which implies that exports are missing in the file:

```
SyntaxError: import not found: default
```

So, do I need to rebuild it, or how to make it work?

Comment: perhaps there isn't a default export, could you try ```import {io} from "/socket.io/socket.io.js```

Comment: Nope, no exports whatsoever: ` SyntaxError: import not found: io`

Comment: As per [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1055) you may want to try ```import io from 'socket.io-client'```

Comment: dang, ignore me

Comment: That is example would be for if you were using Webpack or Babel. Nothing in the ecosystem supports real native implementations of ES6 modules yet, even if the individual browsers are starting to.

Comment: @TomášZato why your `import` statement is so weird? do you use npm ? if so, you should be able to go without absolute or relative path. Like `import io from 'socket.io-client'` sounds good, but `import io from "/socket.io/socket.io.js"` sounds like you're trying to import from absolute path regarding (from app directory or global NODE_MODULES)

Comment: And I didn't get why don't you just copy and paste the code from docs

Comment: a) `npm` has no effect on native ES6 imports - they do require `.js` suffix as well as path and b) the import I use loads Socket.IO build bundled with socketio server - it automatically serves it if you connect it to express.

Comment: How do you pass options in using this syntax? With the CJS version you can give the module params during import eg. require('test')(x,y);

Comment: @backdesk What you refer to is just a shorthand for assigning result of require to a variable and then calling it as a function. You can do this with any other function in any other context. You can do it with constructors too.